# asp.net mvc - Namespace in view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I place using namespace in a view code behind but i can't call any class of this name space in aspx.

In codebehind:

```
using MVCTest.Controller;
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

try to use in your aspx / ascx file

```
<%@ import namespace='your namespace' %>
```

you could also try to import your namespace in the web.config

```
<system.web>
  <pages>
    <namespaces>
      <add namespace='you namespace' />
    </namespaces>
  </pages>
</system.web>
```

Answer (score 10):

Add the **import** statement If you are using the ASP.NET (C#) engine:

```
<%@ Import Namespace="My.Namespace.Path" %>

<html goes here>
    ...
</html>
```

OR

Add the **using** statement to your view if you are using the Razor engine:

```
@using My.Namespace.Path

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "My Page";
    ...
}

<html goes here>
   ...
</html goes here>
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you remember to include the assembly as well? E.g. like this:

```
// system.web / compilation / assemblies
<add assembly="Microsoft.Web.Mvc"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose this is your .Cs file say

> namespace MVCTest.Controller {
>
> ```
> public class Utility
>
> { 
>    public static void func1()
>    {} 
> }
> ```
>
> }

Try calling the function by : Utility.func1()