# Calling HtmlHelper's extension method from within a PartialView

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, partial-views

I'm trying to call a custom HtmlHelper's extension method from a partial view

```
<%: Html.ToRelativeTime(Model.CreatedDate) %>
```

and I get this error:

```
CS1061: ...does not contain a definition for 'ToRelativeTime' and no extension method 'ToRelativeTime' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper...could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

and I'm calling the render code as this:

```
<% Html.RenderPartial("Product", Model.Product); %>
```

P.S: When I type `Html.`, there is no intellesince.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add namespace reference of your extension to the partial view where you trying to use your custom extension

```
<%@ import namespace='your namespace' %>
```

also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/352118/asp-net-mvc-name-space-in-view) you may find a useful information

Comment: Yes this should fix it. I think the syntax is @import Models.MyHtmlHelpersClass or something similar.

Comment: yeah if using Razor.. but in the samples it's not looks so :)

Comment: If it's an HtmlHelper extension, I would prefer the web.config solution.

Comment: Agree, all HtmlHelper extension should be located in the one place and registered via web.config